# Temples to cults or gods?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A question: temples can be dedicated to a single god or a cult, which can worship one or several gods - what is the difference, for example if I dedicate temple to, let's say, God of Fire or to the cult, who worships the same God of Fire?

Answer (score 5):

People who aren't members of that cult won't be able to pray there even if they want to pray to the god of fire.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying